# Opening task manager takes an incredibly long time

Tags: windows-8, task-manager

This happens on all my windows 8 devices.

When I press CTRL + SHIFT + ESC, or just start the task manager in any other way, it always takes a long time to open - Something around 45 seconds to 2 minutes.

In windows 7 and below, taskmanager would open instantly. Why does windows 8 take so much longer? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Run ProcessMonitor in background and look at the duration column what takes so long.

Comment: Magicandre1981, you might want to include a link to ProcessMonitor so that we know what you are talking about. I'm going to guess you mean http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx , but there are several things called "Process Monitor" out there.

Comment: It must be the hard disk usage. I'm facing this issue when the hard disk utilization goes to 85-95%.